# Bigcommerce how to get query string from url to store into global variable

Tags: query-string, bigcommerce

My task is the following, I need a way to store a query string value of s and pass it to the merchants Order Confirmation email.

consider the following,...mybigcommerce.com?s=fb.

Let's say that my client posts his website link to facebook and adds in a query string of s with a value of FB (facebook).

The desired result would be that on the initial load of the page, the query string would be saved as a cookie(or in Bigcommerce's case a global or store front variable)

Once I have it saved, I now know that you just simply append the variable to the email template.

example output:
email template source : %name_of_variable%.

My problem is, however, I don't see how to store the value into a variable.

Can I accomplish this without using the API, or for that matter can I do this using the API?

Thank you in advanced, I hope I have provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot create your own variable in the email templates. The variables used here have been created and are supported by code within the core application. As such, it would require a core application change to extend existing functionality/add a variable. There isn't a way for you to write to an existing variable either.